# Comprobar que hay un caracter y añadir los datos en una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, estoy tratando de obtener de una entrada de usuario, que ha añadido una arroba y en ese caso, coger los caracteres que hay antes de dicha arroba y almacenarlos en una variable. He probado esto pero no me funciona:

```
correo = input("Introduzca su correo electrónico: ")

def funcorreo(cuenta):
    if cuenta == "":
        print ("Error. No ha introducido ningun dato")
    else:
        print ("Comprobando datos introducidos")
        for i in range(len(cuenta)):
            nombr = []
            nombr.append(cuenta[i])
            if cuenta[i] != "@":
                print ("No es arroba. El caracter es " + cuenta[i])
            else:
                print ("Si es una arroba. Ha introducido un caracter correcto")
                print (nombr)

funcorreo(correo)
```

en "nombr" solo está almacenando el último caracter y no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Estoy en Python 3.5.2 bajo Windows.

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que si introduces cualquier caracter que no es una `@` entra en la condición `if cuenta[i] != "@"` y nunca llega a la `@` correcta. En seudocódigo lo que hace es:

```
cuenta = 'pepe@pipi.popo'

para letra en cuenta:
    si letra no es igual a '@':
        # la primera letra es 'p' por lo que ya cumple la condición que no es '@'
        print('booooooooooooom, comprobación incorrecta')
```

rehaciendo un poco tu código y haciéndolo de la forma bruta:

```
correo = input("Introduzca su correo electrónico: ")

def funcorreo(cuenta):
    if cuenta:
        print("Comprobando datos introducidos")
        if '@' in cuenta and cuenta.count('@') == 1:
            return cuenta.split('@')[0]
        else:
            print("Error. No ha introducido ningun dato")

funcorreo(correo)
```

Si probamos la función anterior lo siguiente sería correcto:

```
cuenta = 'pepe@pipi.popo'
funcorreo(cuenta)
```

devuelve `pepe`.

Pero lo siguiente, que no es una dirección de correo válida, también sería correcto y devolvería también `pepe`:

```
cuenta = 'pepe@'
funcorreo(cuenta)
```

Lo normal en estos casos es usar una expresión regular:

```
import re

email_re = re.compile("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+") # un posible ejemplo de regex visto en http://stackoverflow.com/a/8022584/5216568
correo = input("Introduzca su correo electrónico: ")

def funcorreo(cuenta):
    print("Comprobando datos introducidos")
    if email_re.match(cuenta):
        return cuenta.split('@')[0]
    else:
        print('Dirección incorrecta')

funcorreo(correo)
```

En este caso, tanto `pepe@pipi.popo` como `pepe@` darían un resultado satisfactorio.

**Actualización**: Una vez que tienes el *regex*, como indica @Mariano en su comentario de más abajo, puedes devolver parte de la información, como lo que hay antes de `@` usando el método `group` del objeto devuelto por el ``match`en lugar de usar el método`split` de las cadenas. Independientemente de cómo definas tu *regex* eso nunca valdrá para saber si la cuenta de correo es válida o existe, solo vale para saber si está bien construida sintacticamente.

Comment: Si ya estás usando un regex, quizás es más fácil poner la parte antes de la `@` entre paréntesis, y referirla como `m.group(1)`. [Ejemplo](http://ideone.com/DjYfp3)

Comment: Cierto, tienes toda la razón.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, voy a ir probando esto.